# real estate large scale 301 redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to work out what to do in regard to a redirect of a new client real estate website.

We have no access at all to the old site and the url structure on new is forcibly different due to randomly generated property IDs (our system generates a different ID from old)

The old url structure is www.mydomain.com/property/view?=1111

The new url structure is www.mydomain.com/property/street-name/2222

My instinct is to do manual 301s for every property (about 6000), matching by page title, but sadly I cant as I have no access to the structure of the old website and despite spidering it numerous times I cant get a pull of all properties off.

If any could give me any advice on what best to do to avoid bad user experience and a google frying, would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the 1111 is.  If that corresponds to an MLS ID number (some sort of UID) then you should be able to use regex to get it to work.  Most of the IDX vendors offer a way to grab listings via an MLSID.

If that 1111 is instead just a GUID of the previous IDX vendor, then you might be out of luck and would need to do everything manually.